# Vue PWA not getting new content after refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to Vue and created a project with the PWA Service-worker plugin. After deploying a new version of my App I get these messages in console:

[image: Failure]

After refreshing the page (F5) these messages still appear the same way and the App is still in it's old state. I tried everything to clear the cache but it still won't load the new content.

I haven't changed anything from the default config after creating my project and didn't add any code which interacts with the serviceworker. What is going wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try going to the application panel in chrome dev tools and using clear storage there? That's worked for me in the past - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#application

Comment: As said by @chrismarx you need to clear storage from devtools,this might be happening because you might be using a cache first startegy.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As I figured out, this question is really only related to beginners in PWA, which don't know that you can (and need) to configure PWA for achieving this. If you feel addressed now (and using VueJS) remember:

To automatically download the new content, you **need** to configure PWA. In my case (VueJS) this is done by creating a file `vue.config.js` in the root directory of my project (On the same level as `package.json`).

Inside this file you need this:

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        workboxOptions: {
            skipWaiting: true
        }
    }
}
```

Which will automatically download your new content if detected.
However, the content won't be displayed to your client yet, since it needs to refresh after downloading the content. I did this by adding `window.location.reload(true)` to `registerServiceWorker.js` in my `src/` directory:

```
updated () {
    console.log('New content is available: Please refresh.')
    window.location.reload(true)
},
```

Now, if the Service Worker detects new content, it will download it automatically and refresh the page afterwards.

Comment: skipWaiting is not recommended for lazy-loading: If your web app lazy-loads resources that are uniquely versioned with, e.g., hashes in their URLs, it's recommended that you avoid using skip waiting.

Comment: Keep in mind that the skipWaiting option is not available when the workbox plugin mode is set to InjectManifest.

Comment: hmm, when adding the workboxOptions and the window.location.reload my app went into an endless loop of reloading the page :(

Comment: so what is the solution in injectManifest mode? i want to automatically update my service worker on clients. @saawsann

Comment: @TexasJetter did you find a workaround! It is going into endless reloading of page :(

Comment: as MDN says the reload "location.reload() has no parameter".
And continues: "Firefox supports a non-standard forceGet boolean parameter for location.reload(), to tell Firefox to bypass its cache and force-reload the current document. However, in all other browsers, any parameter you specify in a location.reload() call will be ignored and have no effect of any kind."

Comment: Where does one find a list of all available workboxOptions? I understand workbox is its own thing, but it's hard finding the configs specific to the Vue CLI.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out a different approach to this and from what I've seen so far it works fine.

```
updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
      caches.keys().then(function(names) {
        for (let name of names) caches.delete(name);
      });
    },
```

What's happening here is that when the updated function gets called in the service worker it goes through and deletes all the caches. This means that your app will start up slower if there is an update but if not then it will serve the cached assets. I like this approach better because service workers can be complicated to understand and from what I've read using skipWaiting() isn't recommend unless you know what it does and the side effects it has. This also works with injectManifest mode which is how I'm currently using it.

Comment: Deleteing caches cause worker re-registration and creates update loop. How do you prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

pass `registration` argument then use the `update()` with that.
the argument uses [ServiceWorkerRegistration API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration)

```js
updated (registration) {
  console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
  registration.update()
},
```

Comment: didn't work for me( Only this works well
https://dev.to/drbragg/handling-service-worker-updates-in-your-vue-pwa-1pip

Comment: Both solutions create infinite update loop.